# Improve a loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Good afternoon everyone,

I have a problem with a loop in Matlab and I do not know how to improve it. I am going to simplify the question as much as possible. I have the following table:

```
        Phase 1 Phase 2    Phase 3
Case1   10       20        15
Case2   15       339       32
...
```

What I need to do is to create 10 rows (Case 1/Phase 1) with the following information:

```
'Phase 1'  1  0  0 % Each 'phase' has its own information
```

Then, I need to create 20 rows (Case 1/Phase 2) with the following information.

```
'Phase 2'  1  1  0
```

At the moment, I am doing it on that way but I want to automate it.

```
for i= 1:10
c(i,:) = {'Phase 1', 1, 0, 0};
end
for i= 11:31
    c(i,:) = {'Phase 1', 1, 0};
end
```

Any suggestions would be very valuable!

And thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I think you should take a look at the Matlab `repmat` function. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html

Comment: Are "Phases 1,2,3" inputs or are they part of your data structure?